# Why won't Zero-Conf hostname raspberrypi.local resolve on Windows?

Tags: ssh, windows

I have a Raspberry Pi with Wi-Fi off, connected by Ethernet directly to a Windows 10 laptop. The laptop is on Wi-Fi and has internet connection sharing on. I've been running `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` (or similar) via several applications. It worked great until recently; now they all error.

- PuTTY: `Unable to open connection to raspberrypi.local. gethostbyname: unknown error`
- Cygwin: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname raspberrypi.local: No address associated with hostname`
- WinSshFS: `The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found`

Note that these errors are **different** than what I get when I try an invalid `.local` address or when Ethernet is disconnected.

Also note that when I put a router between Pi and Windows, the `raspberrypi.local` hostname works fine. But I don't want my stack to depend on a router.

With the direct Ethernet connection, I can still connect by IP address; but IPs change sometimes. I want to use the Zero-Conf hostname instead.

Answer (score 1):

When I execute `hostname -A` on the Pi, it prints `raspberrypi.mshome.net`.

All my applications can connect to `raspberrypi.mshome.net`. This suits my needs. I still wonder why `raspberrypi.local` is half-way registered.

Comment: This is a windows implementation issue: https://superuser.com/q/491747